# Return alternative number base by parameter function

Tags: php, algorithm

```
function solution($N)
{
$corect = true;
$str = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++) {
    if ($corect) {
     LINE 9:  $str += '+';
    } else {
        $str += '-';
        $corent = !$corent;
    }

}
return $str;
}

echo solution(10);
```

I want to return alternative numbers base by function parameters like $N= 3 output: +-+ .
I tried to do this but i got this error in console

```
  PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in line 9
```

Comment: use `.=` instead of `+=`

Comment: also `$corent` is not defined

Comment: Thanks was my bad about that variable

Comment: depends on your expected output but array_fill might be shorter https://3v4l.org/CulIF

Comment: Thanks for advice

Comment: Also, `$corect` will always be `true`.